# key press function with (+) key doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem here with my keypress function in jquery. i dont know why the keypress function not work. i have use the right code for the key. in my function has 2 code that contain 2 event key press one for (+) code 107 and (enter) code 13. the enter function running well but for (+) not even running or work.

maybe someone can help me for this? this is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var result=0;
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 107) {
        result=result+parseInt($('#date_awal').val());
     $('#date_awal').val("");
    }
 });
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        result=result+parseInt($('#date_awal').val());
     alert("result is "+result); 
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-group" id="date_awal" name="date_awal" />
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is, 107 is the keycode for the `+` in the number pad ...

Answer (score 1):

Use only one `event`  and use `if` condition to match `keyocde`  and I think for (+) `keycode` is 43.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = 0;
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
        if (e.which == 43 ) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#date_awal').val());
            $('#date_awal').val("");
        }
        if (e.which == 13) {
            result = result + parseInt($('#date_awal').val());
            alert("result is " + result);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-group" id="date_awal" name="date_awal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result=0;
$('#date_awal').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 43) {
        result=result+parseInt($(this).val());
       $('#date_awal').val("");
        e.preventDefault();        
    }
    else if(e.which == 13) {
        result=result+parseInt($(this).val()==''?0:$(this).val());
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-group" id="date_awal" name="date_awal" />
```